# Looping Over Creation of Models

Tags: php, laravel

What I'm attempting to do is create 5 new models for each month of the year.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    for ($j = 51; $j <= 55; $j++) {
        factory(Employee::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Employee '. $j,
        ])->employments()->create(['started_at' => now()->subYear(1)->addMonth($i);
    }
}
```

Currently, the problem is that after each month it starts the count back at 51. I'd like it for it to continue on from the last number it was on.

Comment: Is this `51` a special number, Or we can use any number?

Comment: Well before I have 50 models being created so I need to start the number at 51.

Comment: Why do you call `employments()` again after factory function. `factory()->create()->employments()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the printable employee number (previously `$j`) out of the loop so that it won't reset as per the instructions of the `for loop` itself:

```
$eNum = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
   for ($j = 51; $j <= 55; $j++) {
       factory(Employee::class)->create([
           'name' => 'Employee '. $eNum,
       ])->employments()->create(['started_at' => now()->subYear(1)->addMonth($i);
       $eNum ++;
   }
}
```

The `$j` variable doesn't really matter in terms of printing now - and can start at 1 or 51 or whatever you like.  If you are looking to print the number and continue to increment, just keep the printable var (`$eNum`) outside the loop.

Comment: If I run the above-suggested solution I get it started at 51 and then after the first month it would be 56 and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that's possible.  If you run the above solution, `$eNum` starts at 1.  Your first employee name would be "Employee 1" and your last should be "Employee 60".  As I noted in the answer, the `$j` var is not important for the printable stuff.  You *asked* for the number continue on, this is how you do that.

Comment: I need it to start at 51 and for the first month and for every month after that create 5 employees

Comment: No problem - in the very first line set `$enum` to 51.  It will then continue on from 51 to around 110.

Comment: But what about the for ($j = 51; ...) that would no longer work.

Comment: The `$j` variable doesn't matter.  Run the code with `$eNum` set to 51.  You will have "Employee 51" through "Employee 110", which is what you want.  The inner `for loop` variable doesn't matter - you just want to have that thing run 5 times and make 5 employees per month.  You can change that line to read `for ($j = 1; $j <= 5; $j++)` if that makes it more clear for you -- the `$j` var is JUST incrementing the inner loop to make 5 employees.  The `$eNum` var is what you are using as a count to print for the employee names.